# Picking the right chunk sizes for each operation

Tags: arrays, dask

I've been working on a program that requires generating tensors larger than memory, and it is going fairly well with `Dask`. The only issue I've got, is that the operations take long and I'd like to know whether there is a way of speeding up my program.

In particular, the most demanding operation is computing the tensor outer product of a tensor with itself, like this:

```
import dask.array as da
tensor = da.random.random(10, 20)
outer = da.multiply.outer(tensor, tensor)
```

As my resulting arrays are larger than memory (much larger than in the example), I'm storing them using `zarr`:

```
import zarr
storage = zarr.DirectoryStore('a_path')
da.to_zarr(outer, url=storage, compute=True, component='comp')
```

Although if the resulting chunks are larger than `4GB`, I'm rechunking the array again before calling `to_zarr`, because otherwise I get the error: `ValueError: Codec does not support buffers of > 2147483647 bytes`.

I'm working on a machine with around 600 GB of RAM, and my resulting outer products have a size of around 700 GB (but I'd like to go as large as possible).

I've tried running some local experiments, chunking the arrays in different ways (with `rechunk`) and comparing the speeds locally, but I haven't seen much difference.

Also, in particular for the tensor outer product, it seems like the number of operations required grows exponentially with the number of chunks (I evaluated this in a `Jupyter notebook`), and if the tensors are chunked excessively, the computation fails (or I get a performance warning). Also, after computing my tensor outer products, I need to sum them.

So, is there a way to find out what the best way of chunking a tensor is depending on the operation that is going to be computed over it?

Comment: It's more of an art...

Comment: Here are some resources on chunking that might be helpful: [Genevieve Buckley Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/DataNerdery/status/1424953376043790341?s=20), and [Dask Array Best Practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-best-practices.html)